# How to view commands that `make` executes?

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile, which fails at some point, with a `git` error.  How can I view the `git` command that causes the whole make process to fail?  More precisely, I am looking for a list of commands (including the ones that start with `@`) that I can run on an identical setup, to achieve the same effect as what `make` does.

I know for a script, instead of `#! /bin/bash` you would add a flag `-x` to it, and that would display all the commands before their execution.  How do I do the same thing for `make`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Log invoked commands of make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415547/log-invoked-commands-of-make)

Comment: The question "Is there a way to log the commands, make invokes to compile a program?" is the same -- but none of the answers do what I need.  I will now modify the question to make it more clear what I'm looking for.  Thanks for the reference.

Comment: There is another qiestoon which has different answers that may also be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54933242/how-do-i-make-a-makefile-to-log-both-command-and-its-output-to-a-file/54934047

Comment: @CherryDT When I tried the `set -x` answer, here is the beginning of my output: `'[' -e /path/to/dir/Make.user ']'` `uname -m` `uname` `uname` `uname` `uname -m`; and then, this repeats couple times, and I get the output: `make[1]: Entering directory '/path/to/dir'`. Problems with this approach: 1) make doesn't display the command it used to enter this directory. 2) I don't believe the makefile instructs to run `uname` 18 times in a row. So something is going wrong

Comment: @CherryDT So the answer to my question was actually in the *question* that you referenced.  And that is why none of the answers addressed what I needed: because the OP explicitly stated he already knew about it.  The "right" way to achieve what I wanted was to run `make -n`.  As simple as that.  Still no clue why the `SHELL="sh -x"` approach fails though...

Comment: You should not set `SHELL` to a command line.  It should contain only the command (`/bin/sh`).  If you want to change the _arguments_  you need to set `.SHELLFLAGS`.  However, you have to remember to include the default `-c` option otherwise the shell will not work.  So, you should use `make .SHELLFLAGS=-xc`.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for a list of commands (including the ones that start with `@`) that I can run on an identical setup, to achieve the same effect as what `make` does.

By default, `make` echoes all recipe commands it runs, except those prefixed with `@`.  [The POSIX specifications for `make`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html) do not describe a way to override that effect of `@` (but see below).  It is conceivable that your `make` has an extension for that, but the `make` implementations you are most likely to be using (GNU `make` or BSD `make`, since you seem to assume that your standard shell is `bash`) do not.

Additionally, in POSIX-conforming `make` implementations, including the two mentioned above, the special target `.SILENT` can be used to suppress echoing the commands of some or all targets, and the `-s` command-line option can be used to suppress echoing for all targets.

You can print recipe commands prefixed with `@` if you run `make` with the `-n` (no-op) flag.  That will print the commands for out-of-date targets *without running them*, except that those prefixed with a `+` are run even in no-op mode.  Commands prefixed with `@` are included among those printed.  Under some circumstances, the fact that most commands are not actually run in this mode can affect the output, but all the cases I can think of at the moment involve recursive `make`, and I think they are fairly unlikely.

POSIX seems to indicate that `-n` does not override `-s` or `.SILENT`, so if you have to deal with those then you may have no alternative but to modify your makefile.  If you happen to be using GNU `make`, however, you will find that `-n` *does* override `.SILENT` and `-s` in that implementation.  The same may be true of other `make`s.